# Getting an installed module to recognize changes to config files

Tags: config, package, raku

I have a package that uses `config.json` for some settings it uses. I keep the package locally rather than installing it from CPAN. My problem is when I make changes to `config.json`, the package doesn't recognize the changes since the config file's cached elsewhere, forcing me to run `zef install --force-install` or delete precomp. How can I ensure that the package always recognizes updates to the config file?

Comment: Perhaps store the `"config.json".IO.modified` somewhere and see if it changes?

Comment: How would I get the path to the original `config.json` from the binary zef installs?

Comment: It probably gets read at `BEGIN` (compile) time, where you want it to be read at `INIT` time.

Answer (score 4):

When you install packages using [`zef`](https://github.com/ugexe/zef), it keeps them in the filesystem, but their names are converted into sha1, something like

```
/home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.03/install/share/perl6/site/sources/81436475BD18D66BFD96BBCEE07CCCDC0F368879
```

`zef` keeps track of them, however, and you can locate them using `zef locate`, for instance:

```
zef locate lib/Zef/CLI.pm6
```

You can run that from a program, for instance this way:

```
sub MAIN( Str $file ) {
    my $location = qqx/zef locate $file/;
    my $sha1 = ($location ~~ /\s+ \=\> \s+ (.+)/);
    say "$file → $sha1[0]";
}
```

which will return pretty much the same, except it will give you the first location of the file you give it at the command line:

```
lib/Zef/CLI.pm6 → /home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.03/install/share/perl6/site/sources/81436475BD18D66BFD96BBCEE07CCCDC0F368879
```

You probably need to install your `config.json` file in a `resources` directory (which is the preferred location) and then use something like that.

That said, probably actually installing a module you're testing is not the best strategy. If you're still testing things, it's probably better if you just keep it in the directory you're working with and use `perl6 -I<that directory>` or else `use lib <that directory>` is probably a better option. You can just delete that when you release, or keep it, since that only adds another directory to the search path and will not harm the released module.

Comment: I don't install when I'm testing, just when I make changes to `config.json`. I was able to get it to work by moving `config.json` to `resources/` like you said and making a hard link to the location of the cached file. It doesn't matter much to me that linking like this wouldn't be useful if I uploaded to CPAN since I don't plan on doing so

Comment: It's probably not wise to change files inside the installed module location.  Installed distributions are supposed to be immutable and the system relies on that.  If you need additional configuration, you should provide that outside of the installed module database.  See also: https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/241#issuecomment-383823558

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that. Putting the config file somewhere like `~/.config/` makes sense, but what where do files like this usually go on Windows?